# Error: #if[n]def expected an identifier

Tags: c++, identifier, ifndef

Originally my code was:

```
#ifndef 2DO_H   
#define 2DO_H  
int ReadNumber();  
void WriteAnswer(int Nsumber1, int Number2);  
#endif
```

However I was getting an error `#if[n]def expected an identifier`.  So I played around with it and realized that my error was in `2DO_H`.  When I changed my code to:

```
#ifndef DO_H   
#define DO_H  
int ReadNumber();  
void WriteAnswer(int Nsumber1, int Number2);  
#endif
```

It worked in the above case because I changed `2DO_H` to `DO_H`.  Why is it that when I have an extra number in front of the identifier, I get an error?

Comment: It's the same set of restrictions as variable names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because identifiers aren't allowed to start with a digit. This is covered in `2.11 Identifiers` of the current C++ 11 standard, specifically the syntax section:

```
identifier:
    identifier-nondigit               # No digit allowed at front here.
    identifier identifier-nondigit    # Nor here.
    identifier digit                  # Nor here.
```

Comment: But is there a reason for this?  Why is it that in C++ this happens?  There has to be a reason for this because right now I don't see why have numbers in front of an identifier is bad in a programming language.

Comment: @Justin, the reason why it's in C++ is because it was in C (C++ was originally just a layer on top of C). The reason why it's in C probably has to do with the fact that it's easier to keep numbers and identifiers distinct if you can tell the difference _early._ This greatly eases the task of the compilers (parsers/lexers) which, back when C was young, weren't that clever :-) Think of the identifier `3141592653589x` which you wouldn't know is not a integer until you get to the last character.

Comment: @Justin and the situation gets a lot more complicated when also considering literals such as 0x3F, which is, in fact, a number.

Answer (score 3):

```
#ifndef 2DO_H
```

Nah.

```
#ifndef TODO_H
```

instead. An identifier can't begin with a digit.